# Referencing Files In A Github Markdown File

Tags: github

I am trying to create a readme on github like the following https://github.com/fleejy/ckme136-capstone

I guess my question is how did this content creator create the links under the Documentation And Repository Organization heading in the Readme.md file as I would like to emulate this.

I did some searching for relative references examples but was not able to figure it out.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just look at the [markdown source](https://github.com/fleejy/ckme136-capstone/blob/master/README.md?plain=1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very Simple, you have to make a URL in markdown referring to your folder/file.

For making a URL in markdown files you use a syntax like this `[Text](exampleURL)` here your `Text` is the text which will appear in the markdown file and the `exampleURL` is the URL you want to go to.

A Working Example Will Be Like this `[Google](https://google.com)`.

If you want to refer to a particular file/folder inside your repository you don't need `https://` all you need is to provide the path of the folder/file

for example in my repository i have a file named `example.pdf` inside a folder named `PDFs` so my markdown code will look like this `[Example PDF](PDFs/example.pdf)`

Markdown is pretty easy and you can learn markdown syntax with this [CheatSheet](https://github.com/tchapi/markdown-cheatsheet).

Comment: Thanks very much for that clear explanation.